# State Model Representation of RLC network

Tags: circuit-analysis, control, control-system, state-space

[image]

I am confused with the above problem. Should I take a new state variable for rightmost capacitor or 3 variables are sufficient?

Please help me in writing the state space equations.

Comment: You should take the output state. There is a general rule for this relating to capacitive loop and inductive cutset in the link below.

https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=ZlJM1OLDQx0C&pg=SA10-PA1&lpg=SA10-PA1&dq=%22independent%22+%22state+variable%22+%22capacitive+loop%22&source=bl&ots=LLP2XNhrsa&sig=FeUO6GS9mAND8InBO3ECGbvCNrE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcuMGZ7unZAhVFlZQKHeB8CIcQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22independent%22%20%22state%20variable%22%20%22capacitive%20loop%22&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 4 variables and there are 4 equations

$$V_{\text{C1}}-V_{\text{C2}}=L_4 i_1'$$
$$i_1=\frac{V_i-V_{\text{C1}}}{R_2}-C_3 V_{\text{C1}}'$$
$$i_1=C_4 \left(V_0'-V_{\text{C2}}'\right)+\frac{V_{\text{C2}}}{R_5}$$
$$\frac{V_{\text{C2}}-2 V_0}{R_6}=C_4 V_0'$$

And there are 4 unknowns \$\{i_1',V_{\text{C1}}',V_{\text{C2}}',V_0'\}\$ from which you can solve for the \$A\$ and \$B\$ matrices.

$$ A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{L_4} & -\frac{1}{L_4} & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{C_3} & -\frac{1}{C_3 R_2} & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{C_4} & 0 & -\frac{-R_5-R_6}{C_4 R_5 R_6} & -\frac{2}{C_4 R_6} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{C_4 R_6} & -\frac{2}{C_4 R_6} \\
\end{array}
\right),B=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 \frac{1}{C_3 R_2} \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I am also attaching the computations in Mathematica
[image]

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation. My instructor combined the capacitor in series and then left the saying that you guys can do from here.

Comment: I think your equations are wrong. Please correct them.

Comment: All 4? Could you be more specific.